# Fetching JSON object from Servlet Java

Tags: java, json, servlets, post, gson

I want to create an application that will fetch a JSON object from a servlet to deserialize it, and then use its variables to do other things.

My servlet has the following code in the doPost:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

      ObjectOutputStream os;
      os = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

      String s = new String("A String");

      Gson gson = new Gson();
      String gsonObject= gson.toJson(s);

      os.writeObject(gsonObject);
      os.close();

    }
```

Now, while the servlet is running, I can access it via a browser, if I post same code in the doGet method, that would download a servlet file, which is not what I want.

What should I use in my second application that would connect to the servlet, fetch the object, so that I can manipulate it later?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your second application ? Rendering a html page or read and process from Java Code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need few changes in your servlet :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
   String s = new String("A String");
 String json = new Gson().toJson(s);
 this.response.setContentType("application/json");
 this.response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 Writer writer = null;
 try {
        writer = this.response.getWriter();
        writer.write(json);
 } finally {
    try {
        writer.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't fully solve my problem, but it helped a lot and actually got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If its downloading the servlet file instead of showing it in the browser , most probably you have not set the  content type in the response. If you are writing a JSON string as the servlet response , you have to use

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Please note the order , its "text/html" and not "html/text"

Answer (score 0):

IfI understood the question correctly then you can use, `java.net.HttpURLConnection` and `java.net.URL` objects to create a connection to this servlet and read the JSON streamed by the above JSON servlet in your second servlet.